# ColdFusion 11 not starting on OSX

Tags: macos, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I'm having trouble with ColdFusion 11 on OSX.

Getting the following Error:

> ./coldfusion: line 94:  8033 Abort trap: 6           $JAVA_EXECUTABLE
>   -classpath $CLASSPATH $JVM_ARGS com.adobe.coldfusion.bootstrap.Bootstrap -start There has been an
>   error starting ColdFusion 11 server, please check the logs.

Has anyone one come across this?

Comment: Can you confirm that the "JRE" exists at /ColdFusion 11/ location?

Comment: Thank You that was the issue, had to install Java on a brand new iMac.